# What's the meaning of "go around"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Mr. Netanyahu sparked a controversy when he and House Speaker John
>   Boehner **went around** the White House and arranged a visit and speech on
>   Capitol Hill without consulting anyone in the State Department or the
>   administration, in an open effort to derail U.S.-led nuclear
>   negotiations with Iran. -CNN Student News-

What's the meaning of "went around" in this sentence? 
Does it mean that they visited the White House?

Comment: It means visited.

Comment: @Khan Not in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "went around" means "circumvented." Boehner acted without asking the permission of certain other individuals, thus "going around" them. Picture Obama and his administration standing in a doorway, and Boehner "going around" them.

Answer (score 0):

*Went around* means they avoided the White House; they didn't include anyone in the Obama administration in the decision to invite the person.